# Hamcrest Matchers - Assert Type of List

Tags: java, assert, matcher, hamcrest

**The Problem**

I'm currently trying to use Hamcrest Matchers to assert that the list type being returned is of a specific type.  For example, let's say I have the following List that is being returned by my service call:

```
List<SomePOJO> myList;
```

I want to assert that the list being returned is parametrized of type `SomePOJO` and not `TheOtherPOJO`.  However, it appears that Hamcrest Matchers does not have this sort of functionality.

**What I Have Tried**

After some research, I have seen the following options:

1. I have seen that there is `hasItem(isA(SomePJO.class))`, however this only works if there is an element in the list, and not if the list is empty.
2. I *could* use `is(instanceOf(List.class))`, however this will only assert that the item being returned is a List; it does not assert what *type* of list is being returned.
3. I can also add an element to the list immediately before the assert statement and then using `assertThat(somePojo.get(0), is(instanceOf(SomePOJO.class)))`, however this isn't very clean.  It is also very similar to point #1.

**Conclusion / The Question**

Using Hamcrest Matchers, is there a way to assert that an empty list is parametrized of a certain type (such as `assertThat(myList, is(aListOf(SomePOJO.class)))`)?

Comment: You can write a custom matcher for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  This is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you're not able to inspect the generic type.  The compiler will enforce this for you.  If you really want to test this, one option would be to grab the first element and make sure you can cast it to `SomePOJO`. (or alternatively grab *every* element and attempt the cast, but I believe this is overkill).

Comment: I thought that may be the issue, however I was being hopeful (mainly since Mockito has a `anyListOf(Class.clazz)` method which unfortunately doesn't work in this case).  Guess I'll just stick with the third option I could come up with. Thanks

Comment: @MikeKoch Yeah, check out https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/org/mockito/Matchers.java#L341.  It actually just is for use with generics to suppress warnings.  It doesn't actually do that ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I saw when I looked it up on GrepCode :( . Oh well.

Comment: What about adding an instance of the desired type? If it's a list with a different type, won't it throw an exception?

Comment: @DavidHarkness Nope, at runtime a `List<SomeObject>` becomes `List<Object>`.  The only way to determine the type of the objects in the list would be to read the elements and attempt the cast.  All of this is redundant though because the compiler will enforce this.  The only reason you'd need this is if you're messing with reflective calls, etc.