# Mockito check parameter is of Map class

Tags: java, mockito

I am using `Mockito` to test whether the parameter of a function is a `Map`. Right now I am using

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
any(Map.class)
```

but I want to check whether it is of `Map<String, String>` so how would it look like?

`any(Map<String, String>.class)`?

Comment: I don't think there are a lot of situations where you need to use the `any` matcher at all... you'd need to post more code to be able to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.mockito.Matchers` seems to be deprecated and it's recommended to use Hamcrest matchers.

Unfortunately, would you switch to Hamcrest or not, what you're trying to do seems to be impossible anyway, see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935414/hamcrest-matchers-assert-type-of-list).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Matchers.<Map<String, String>>any()
```

Comment: Thanks for this proposition, this seem to solve the warning for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `import org.mockito.Mockito;`

```
Mockito.anyMapOf(String.class, String.class);
```